# Is arm_neon.h missing all float16_t types?

Tags: android, arm, simd, neon

I'm using NEON SIMD instruction to write a part of an Android app, targeting Cortex A8 processors. According to [this reference manual](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.dui0491c/DUI0491C_arm_compiler_reference.pdf), NEON supports 16-bit and 32-bit floats, that is `float16_t` and `float32_t`. When I tried using `float16_t` and all of its associated vector types, I got an error saying that this type is undeclared. When looking through contents of `arm_neon.h`, I found that this type is indeed undeclared.

Is there a reason for this? ARM's Advanced SIMD obviously supports such data types and instructions. Has anyone encountered / resolved this? Is it documented anywhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you specify an example section in the document you linked where these 16 bit float operations are called out?  I see quite a few 16 bit integer operations defined.  Are you using ARM's compiler or gcc?  And are you talking about SIMD or NEON?

"NEON™ technology builds on the concept of SIMD with a dedicated module to provide 128-bit wide vector operations, compared to the 32bit wide SIMD in the ARMv6 architecture."

EDIT:

I tried this with no compiler complaints:

```
int myfun ( int a)
{
    __fp16 b;

    b=a+1;

    return(b+1);
}
```

using this command line:

```
arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc -S -mcpu=mpcore -mfp16-format=ieee -mfpu=neon-fp16  simd.c
```

Using codesourcery lite 2011.03

```
arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc --version
arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc (Sourcery G++ Lite 2011.03-41) 4.5.2
Copyright (C) 2010 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Comment: I'm using NEON with GCC, but it's simply an extension of existing SIMD, like you mentioned above.

Comment: The ARM toolchain manual which you referenced is for the ARM toolchain not gcc.  Apples and oranges.  Need to find gcc documentation indicating what it does and doesnt support..

Comment: Yep, right here http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Half_002dPrecision.html#Half_002dPrecision

Comment: I assume you are using a combination of those command line options?

Comment: It seems like GCC does not accept those recognize these command like options at all. I'm going to update my question.

Comment: hmmm, interesting that they say __fp16 is a storage format only (no math operations).

Comment: Thanks. I was using an older GCC version compiler. These flags were only added in 4.5.x

Comment: arm_neon.h however still does not define 16-bit float types. I guess I'll just have to stick to 32-bit floats for now.

Comment: Yeah, I didnt take it that far, as a result of your question I was learning about this new-to-me half precision format, and these simd/neon command line options.  To actually make float16 useful (and not just get it tied to traditional single precision math) you do need some way to shove those numbers into these new multi-vector instructions.  Might want to just implement the functions yourself (in assembler) and call them from C.  You will get exactly the functionality you want out of the processor that way.

Comment: Makes sense, I was thinking the same thing. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

Cortex-A8 processors do not support 16-bit floats in hardware.

**Cortex-A9** processors *do* have instructions to convert between 16- and 32-bit floating-point, but that's all you get (and that's all that should be provided on an IEEE-754 system -- float16 is not intended for arithmetic, only for compact storage).  The usage model is to load float16 data, convert it to float32 to do your arithmetic, and then convert back to float16 before storing.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, not too familiar with SIMD instructions. The document you posted does not mention float16_t, but instead uses the number of lanes as well (e.g. float16x4_t)

Also, did you try "Float16_t" instead of "float16_t" ?

This is my home laptop, so I don't have access to the ARM compiler, but I'll try and recheck this tomorrow in the office

Comment: ahh, I see a number of float16s now.

Comment: The NEON intrinsic function prototypes that use __fp16 are only available for targets that have
the NEON half-precision VFP extension. To enable use of __fp16, use the --fp16_format
command-line option. See --fp16_format=format on page 3-57. are you using the --fp16_format command line option and do you have a NEON that supports half precision floating point formats?

Comment: Well, here's a [page of GNU compiler's documentation](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Half_002dPrecision.html#Half_002dPrecision) that documents using those flags. However, GCC does not seem to accept them. I'm looking into the problem, but I suspect that Android NDK (which I'm using) comes with an older version of GCC for one reason or another.

Comment: sorry, sorry, added comments to the wrong answer, was trying to add to my answer.