# Build android shared object from makefile

Tags: android, facebook, unity-game-engine, dll, zstd

I want to include [Facebook's zstd](https://github.com/facebook/zstd) into my Unity project targetting Android.

The contributors made it easily to build `.dll` for .Net platform. But I can't make it work on the Android build, it only work on the Editor. Seems like the library depends on `msvcr120.dll` or `msvcr140.dll` so it can't be loaded on Android.

So I am looking for a way (or a keyword) to build `.so` library so I can have it work on Android deployment. But [the guide on the Google developer's page](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/add-native-code?hl=en) seems to build an `.apk` with a grade project instead of just building the library from `makefile` and some `.h`, `.c` files.

Comment: I was just found out that `zstd` can not be able to deploy to Android because it doesn't support float16 (see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6588866/is-arm-neon-h-missing-all-float16-t-types ) so I quit using zstd on my android project. Now I just want to know to to build .so from makefile. Thank you for reading.